# Ignore bad records and still update all the good ones in a stored procedure. Log the errors

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have to rework a bunch of complex stored procedures in SQL Server to make them ignore all the records that would cause errors at runtime and still insert/update the correct records. I should also track all the error messages in a separate log table. Currently each procedure is 'wrapped' within a transaction and there is a TRY..CATCH block, so in case of any error, the transaction is rolled back. I would like to know how can I change this behavior but maintain the efficiency as high as possible.

I have scratched and example, to be easier to test.

```
--temporary table created for testing purposes
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temptable

CREATE TABLE #temptable  
(
    [name] varchar(50), 
    [divisible] int,
    [divider] int,
    [result] float
)
GO

--insert some dummy records in #temptable
-- example of a record with good data
INSERT INTO #temptable ([name], [divisible], [divider]) VALUES ('A', 1, 1)
-- example of a record with bad data
INSERT INTO #temptable ([name], [divisible], [divider]) VALUES ('B', 2, 0)
-- another example of a record with good data
INSERT INTO #temptable ([name], [divisible], [divider]) VALUES ('C', 3, 1)

--A dummy example for unhandled error (I know how to handle it otherwise ;-) )
UPDATE #temptable
SET [result] = divisible/divider

SELECT * FROM #temptable
```

Currently nothing gets updated:

[image: Result 1]

I would like to have the good records (A and C) updated and to log the error message that record B will throw.

Also, please keep in mind that I have the freedom to introduce SSIS in the solution, but I don't want to rewrite all the procedures.

So what would you suggest - cursor, while loop, SSIS, or anything else?

Comment: Your goal is to be able to `insert` "bad" data, i.e. data that cannot survive an `update`, successfully? And to have an `update` statement that processes all of the "good" rows while ignoring the others?

Comment: I believe this question is far too broad for this forum. I've spent the day writing about 300 lines of SQL code to do pre-insert validation for one table, and I'm not done yet. In order for something like this to work _efficiently_, you need to anticipate the potential errors and code around them, not capture the errors when they occur. Anything involving row-by-row processing is going to be agonizingly slow (hence Jeff Moden's infamous `RBAR` acronym; Row By Agonizing Row). This is a worthwhile task, but "How do I write defensive code?" is a book, not a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

You need a layered approach for building a solution given the situation:

Layer 1 that runs first -

- Do due diligence on acceptable data range and unacceptable outliers.
  eg. -ve numbers, precision, max -+numbers.
- Do some work on writing
  code for a validation phase where you identify such records in your
  process table and Move them (ie. in a single "`begin tran ... commit
  tran`" section insert - delete them from Processing table, move to Log
  table).

Layer 2 runs second -

- Proceed to perform your Update statement.

Although this suggestion is outside your question, I recommend using a numeric or a decimal instead of float data type. You may run into issues with float.